Can I travel to Mexico with a UK refugee travel document?
I have Eritrea citizenship but I have a UK refugee travel document. Can I travel to Mexico without a visa?

UK citizens do not need a visa to visit Mexico. But have you asked the Mexico embassy in London? The UK government says "Ask the authorities of the country you’re visiting if the country accepts refugee travel documents, and if you need a visa to enter the country".

No, according to IATA
Inputting your travel document as 1951 Convention, the response is:

Visa required.
Visa Exemptions:
Passengers with a multiple-entry visa issued by Canada, Japan, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State for a maximum stay of 180 days.

You can confirm the result by inputting the full details of your proposed trip via the link above.
